# Extract image urls using regex from a text

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract all image urls from a html text that contains a specific word. I tried the following regex but it fails on some string that doesn't have spaces in it.

Regex

```
(http\S+logo\S+[.]png|http\S+logo\S+[.]jpg|http\S+logo\S+[.]svg|http\S+logo\S+[.]jpeg)
```

Text

```
https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/logos/trips-og-1280x630-9de9c338cc3fd9b5663fb80be0cbe8c2.jpg
https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/logos/trips-og-1280x630-9de9c338cc3fd9b5663fb80be0cbe8c2.png
https://a0.muscache.com/airbnb/static/logos/trips-og-1280x630-9de9c338cc3fd9b5663fb80be0cbe8c2.svg
https://media.glassdoor.com/sqls/575263/uber-squarelogo-1537216184790.png","logo2x":"https://media.glassdoor.com/sqlm/575263/uber-squarelogo-1537216184790.png
"https://media.glassdoor.com/sqls/575263/uber-squarelogo-1537216184790.png","logo2x":"https://media.glassdoor.com/sqlm/575263/uber-squarelogo-1537216184790.png"
```

Can anyone ecplain how to extract image urls from above ?

Comment: if you're trying to parse json as string using regex, maybe look into `json.loads`?

Comment: why use a regex? u only need the last item:
str.split("/")[-1]

Comment: Which specific word? It seem to me that you have to work on your regexp. Match first all links (inclusing supported image extension for example), then select those that contain the word you are looking for.

Comment: You can just look for the file extensions. If something ending with a image extension, probably that's an image right?

Comment: Can you show the inputs also?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Like I have explained in the question that the text needs to be extracted from a html content. Why do you think that it has anything to do with json ?

Comment: @lolu Please read the question first. Image URL extraction from html using regex.

Comment: Try this regex: ```https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)[.a-zA-Z]```

Comment: What, exactly, do you want to extract?

Comment: If it is the entire URL, then `https:.*?\.(?:png|jpg|svg)`.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the entire URL, perhaps, simply:

```
https:.*?\.(?:png|jpg|svg)
```